# How to set cookie from CookieManager when using HttpUrlConnection?

Tags: java, http, cookies

I'm perform a http request with some cookie, My code like this:

```
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) u.openConnection();
CookieManager cookieManager = new CookieManager();
cookieManager.setCookiePolicy(CookiePolicy.ACCEPT_ALL);
cookieManager.getCookieStore().add(....);//here to set cookie
CookieHandler.setDefault(cookieManager);
// do request in following
```

But I can't find my cookie by fiddler. I have search many questions in stackoverflow, none of them work through. So, please help me to find the way to set cookie.

P.S. I don't want to use `Cookie` header.

Answer (score 3):

finally , I found the problem , CookieHandler.setDefault() should be call before any Http operation, in my code ,it should before `u.openConnection()`.